# Regex matching inside a sentence and/or a range of characters

Tags: regex, wildcard

I am trying to find a term that follows a known 'anchor' word. So far I have done so with something similar to the following:

```
 Weight(:( )?)(\d{1,2} lbs|pounds|ounces|kilos)
```

so a string like

- *Weight: 10 lbs*

returns "10 lbs" to me (in fact I identify the digit and the measure with namegroups but I digress). I've found in some cases there can be some text beforehand e.g

- *Weight: up to 10 lbs*

or

- *Weight: can be up to or not more then 10 lbs.*

I'm looking to insert some regex between that will either allow for a reasonable # of random characters or any # of random characters with a period or line return. I tried as one option

```
Weight(:( )?)(.*?)(?P<WEIGHT>(\d{1,2} lbs|pounds|ounces|kilos))[.\n]
```

but this returns many false positives. So essentially looking for:

Weight:(Any reasonable # of characters but not a period or new line)(Value)Measure)

which would account for most variations of the sentence required.

The closest I got was with

```
Weight[^.]{1,30}(?P<WEIGHT>(\d{1,5})( Pounds| Kilos))
```

But the test string of

- "Weight can be 250 Pounds"

returns

- "WEIGHT   [16-24] `0 Pounds`"

Where as the test string without the wildcards

```
(?P<WEIGHT>(\d{1,5})( Pounds| Kilos))
```

returns

- WEIGHT    [14-24] `250 Pounds`

which is exactly what I am looking for (in context to this example)

Comment: Do you want to exclude non-numeric characters so `Weight might be around 250` would capture only `Weight` and `250`? If so, how does this not match your criteria: `Weight[^.\n\r\d]+(\d+(?: Pounds| Kilos))`

Comment: You can add negative lookbehind `(?<!\d)` just before number group as follows: `Weight[^.]{1,30}(?P<WEIGHT>(?<!\d)(\d{1,5})( Pounds| Kilos))`

Comment: @OnlineCop No in fact this was just an example of a much more complex regex which inlcudes patterns with non-numeric characters as well. However the above does work well enough where I can adjust accommodate thank you

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov the negative look behind was just what I needed I think (learn something new each day, just a week into regex here) it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
/weight.*?\s(?P<number>\d+)\s+(?P<name>(?:lb|pound|ounce|kilo)s?)(?:$|\s|\pP)/i
```

- "weight" followed by anything (not greedy)
- A number with whitespace surrounding it
- A name with end-of-string, a space or punctuation following it

In one of your previous questions you use PHP. Here is some test code:

```
$regex = '/weight.*?\s(?P<number>\d+)\s+(?P<name>(?:lb|pound|ounce|kilo)s?)(?:$|\s|\pP)/i';
$tests = array(
    'Weight: 65 lbs',
    'Weight: up to 1 kilo',
    'Weight: can be up to or not more then 10 lbs.',
    'Weight can be 250 ounces',
    'His weight is around 75 kilos',
    'He is very heavy -- about 190 kilos!',
);
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    preg_match($regex, $test, $match);
    if (empty($match)) {
        echo "No match (\"$test\")<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Match: {$match['number']} {$match['name']} (\"$test\")<br>";
    }
}
```